# Prove that $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-xy}(\sin x)\,dy\,dx=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xy}(\sin x)\,dx\,dy$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, uniform-convergence

By theorem. Let $f(x,y)$ be continuous on $[a,\infty) \times [c,\infty)$, and assume that the integrals $\int_a^{\infty}|f(x,y)|\,dx$ and $\int_c^\infty |f(x,y)|\,dy$ converge uniformly in every compact interval $[c,d]$ and $[a,b]$,respectively. Then

$$\int_c^\infty \int_a^\infty f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_a^\infty \int_c^\infty f(x,y) \, dy \, dx.$$

I have $f(x,y)=e^{-xy}\sin x$

I want to prove that $$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xy}(\sin x) \,dy \, dx = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-xy}(\sin x)\,dx\,dy.$$

Question : 1. How to prove $f(x,y)=e^{-xy}\sin x$ is continuous on $[0,\infty) \times [0,\infty)$.

2. How to prove $\int_0^\infty e^{-xy}(\sin x)\,dx$ converge uniformly on $[0,d]$ and $\int_0^\infty e^{-xy}(\sin x)\,dy$ converge uniformly on $[0,b]$.

I know that the definition says $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ if given $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\forall n \geq N$, such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon, \forall n \geq N$.

I would be really happy if someone could help me. Thank you.

Comment: Since $\left|\sin(x)\right|\leq 1$ and $e^{-xy}$ is an integrable function over $\mathbb{R}^+$ (with respect to both the $x$ and $y$ variables), Fubini's theorem applies.

Comment: You can verify your equality directly by doing the integrals.

Comment: @JackDAurizio: As far as I can see, we have $\int_0^\infty e^{-xy}\,dx = 1/y $ which is not integrable on $(0,\infty) $ with respect to $y $.

Comment: I think one problem is that you do not know what it means for the integrals to converges uniformly. Look here http://planetmath.org/uniformconvergenceofintegral.

Comment: Wikipedia on Fubini: "One may switch the order of integration if the double integral yields a finite answer when the integrand is replaced by its absolute value." Unfortunately $\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-xy}|\sin(x)|\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty\left|\frac{\sin(x)}x\right|\mathrm{d}x=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm too lazy to check some uniform convergences, so here is a sketch:
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xy}\sin x \,dy \, dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \frac{\pi}2,\\
\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-xy}\sin x\,dx\,dy = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{Im} \int_0^\infty e^{-xy + ix}\,dx\,dy = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{Im} \frac{1}{y -i}\,dy\\ =\int_0^\infty  \frac{1}{y^2 +1 }\,dy = \frac{\pi}2.
$$

Comment: Yes,i got it.Thank you for mentions.but i want to check some uniform convergences. :D

Comment: @Argento, you cannot prove it in the form you wrote. In fact, $\int_0^\infty |f(x,y)| dx$ is not  uniformly convergent on $[0,d]$ (it even diverges for $y=0$).